# C# XPath id() not working?

Tags: c#

I'm using C# and I'm stumped. Does it just not support id()? I have a large XML file, about 4-5 of them at ~400kb, so I need some speed and performance wherever I can get it.

I use XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("id('blahblahblah')") and it doesn't get the node by id. Am I going crazy or is it that C# XPath just doesn't support id()?

Answer (score 5):

Use [XmlDocument.GetElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx) to get the XmlElement with the specified ID, e.g.:

```
XmlElement elem = doc.GetElementById("blahblahblah");
```

This works only with documents specifying a DTD though:

> Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined in the DTD.

---

In case your document does not have a DTD, you could use an XPath expression to select the node with the *id* attribute set to your ID:

```
XmlElement elem = doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='blahblahblah']");
```

Comment: +1 for clarifying that the id() function is tied to the corresponding reference in the DTD.

Comment: How would I reference the DTD? I mean I know how to do it, I just want to make sure it'll work, so I might as well ask that too. I found this:


<root 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="D:\Untitled1.xsd">
    <file id="F001" title="abc" size="123"/>
    <file id="F002" title="xyz" size="789"/>
    <notification id="PINK" title="Pink Flowers"/>
</root>
In Untitled1.xsd schema (elided for clarity) id attributes are declared as xs:ID.



So what would be in the Untitles1.xsd?

http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000060.html

Ugh. Hey howto BB

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlDocument.GetElementById("blahblahblah")
```

might be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

"Official" XPath [recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id) says that:

> The `id` function selects elements by their unique ID

Where

> An element node may have a unique identifier (ID). This is the value of the attribute that is declared in the DTD as type ID. No two elements in a document may have the same unique ID. If an XML processor reports two elements in a document as having the same unique ID (which is possible only if the document is invalid) then the second element in document order must be treated as not having a unique ID.
>
> NOTE: If a document does not have a DTD, then no element in the document will have a unique ID.